# Two tags with the same name but different location xml

Tags: python, json, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I want to make an XML file into a JSON file in Python. I'm currently trying to extract the information from the XML file to make it into a dict or dataframe.

Here is the XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Terms>
    <Term>
        <Title>.177 (4.5mm) Airgun</Title>
        <Description>The standard airgun calibre for international target shooting.</Description>
        <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
                <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
                <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
        </RelatedTerms>
    </Term>
    <Term>
        <Title>.22</Title>
        <Description>A rimfire calibre, much used in target shooting and often synonymous with the term smallbore.</Description>
        <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
                <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
                <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
        </RelatedTerms>
    </Term>
    <Term>
        <Title>.22 Long Rifle</Title>
        <Description>The standard .22 rimfire cartridge for target rifle and pistol use.</Description>
        <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
                <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
                <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
        </RelatedTerms>
    </Term>
    <Term>
        <Title>.22 Short</Title>
        <Description>Used as a target shooting round for timed fire pistol competitions.</Description>
        <RelatedTerms>
            <Term>
                <Title>Shooting sport equipment</Title>
                <Relationship>Narrower Term</Relationship>
            </Term>
        </RelatedTerms>
    </Term>
</Terms>
```

When I go to call on the *Title* tag it gives me all the Title tags. However, I want to separate the main *Title* tag and the Title tag embedded in the *RelatedTerms* tag.

```py
xml_file = open('xml.xml', encoding='UTF-8') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, 'lxml-xml', from_encoding='UTF-8')


Terms = soup.select('Terms > Term')
jsonObj = {"thesaurus": []}

for term in Terms:
    termDetail = {
        "Description": term.find('Description').text,
        "Title": term.find('Title').text
    }
    RelatedTerms = term.select('RelatedTerms > Term')
    if RelatedTerms:
        termDetail["RelatedTerms"] = []
        for rterm in RelatedTerms:
            termDetail["RelatedTerms"].append({
                "Title": rterm.find('Title').text,
                "Relationship": rterm.find('Relationship').text
            })
    jsonObj["thesaurus"].append(termDetail)

print(json.dumps(jsonObj))
```

Okay so I've Updated the code above, it mostly works. However, the `"Title": rterm.find('Title').text` code gives the error

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I'm not sure why, because there is text in there

Comment: Can you post the actual text of the XML, instead of an image of text, and additionally the code you're using that you're having problems with?

Comment: I have tried adding the actual file but it wont let me, I can try add the code that I've done so far

Comment: You cannot add files to SO questions directly, what you can do however is to add the text _inside_ of the xml-file to the question in its own code-block.

Comment: done, is that better? its not the whole xml file as its a pretty big file, but hopefully you can get an idea of the structure. There are some *RelatedTerms* tags that have multiple *titles* and *Relationship* in them as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use [parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to pull your data out - your data is embedded in terms and relationship, so adapt your code accordingly :

```
from parsel import Selector

data = """[your code above here]"""

selector = Selector(data)

#extract titles in Terms : 
title_in_terms = selector.xpath(".//terms/term/title/text()").getall()
title_in_terms
['.177 (4.5mm) Airgun', '.22', '.22 Long Rifle', '.22 Short']
#extract title in relationship terms: 
title_in_relationship_terms = selector.xpath(".//relatedterms/term/title/text()").getall()
title_in_relationship_terms
['Shooting sport equipment',
 'Shooting sport equipment',
 'Shooting sport equipment',
 'Shooting sport equipment']
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a working solution that uses only packages you specified in your code. It looks like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import lxml

xml_file = open('xml.xml', encoding='UTF-8')
soup = bs(xml_file, 'lxml-xml', from_encoding='UTF-8')

term = soup.find_all('Term')[0]
main_title = term.find_all('Title')[0]
related_terms = term.find_all('RelatedTerms')[0]
embedded_title = related_terms.find_all('Title')[0]

print(main_title.string)
print(embedded_title.string)
```

Output:

```
.177 (4.5mm) Airgun
Shooting sport equipment
```

The code takes strong guarantee that all tags have at least one specified sub-tag. So if you had a XML file without that guarantee, you have to check that list of result tags is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Using only `BeautifulSoup`, when `xml_text` is your xml text from the question, then this script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_text, 'xml')

data = []
for title, description in zip(soup.select('Terms > Term > Title'), soup.select('Terms > Term > Description')):
    data.append({'Title': title.get_text(strip=True),
                 'Description': description.get_text(strip=True),
                 'Related Terms': [(rel_title.get_text(strip=True), rel.get_text(strip=True)) for rel_title, rel in zip(
                        title.find_parent('Term').select('RelatedTerms > Term > Title'),
                        title.find_parent('Term').select('RelatedTerms > Term > Relationship') )]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Created Pandas dataframe:

```
                 Title                                        Description                                Related Terms
0  .177 (4.5mm) Airgun  The standard airgun calibre for international ...  [(Shooting sport equipment, Narrower Term)]
1                  .22  A rimfire calibre, much used in target shootin...  [(Shooting sport equipment, Narrower Term)]
2       .22 Long Rifle  The standard .22 rimfire cartridge for target ...  [(Shooting sport equipment, Narrower Term)]
3            .22 Short  Used as a target shooting round for timed fire...  [(Shooting sport equipment, Narrower Term)]
```